# Calculate md5 on a single 1T file, or on 100 10G files, which one is faster? Or the speed are the same?

Tags: performance, md5

I have a huge 1T file on my local machine and one on the remote server. I need to calculate their md5 to check if they are exactly the same. Since it will take long time to calculate md5 from them, I want to do some research on the md5 speed. I can calculate md5 directly against the whole file, or split it into 100 10G files and calculate md5 on them. I want to know which one is faster, or will they have the same speed?

Comment: It's likely to depend on lots of things - the speed of your disk subsystem, the performance of your CPU, whether you are able to multiprocess with multiple cores and so on.

Comment: If the hardware is the same, then the speed of disk subsystem and the performance of CPU are the same. If I use the same application to calculate md5, then whether it's able to run on multiple cores is not relevant. Here I just want to compare the md5 calculation speed with the same algorithm, once for a huge file or multiple times for many small files.

Comment: The time to read a file can be much bigger than the time to compute the MD5. This will be the case on any platform with an HDD and a modern processor. On such platform, there will be no significant difference between the two methods. If the target storage device is a fast Nvme SSD, then it could have an impact if the chunks are computed in parallel as shown by @Mark. However, in sequential, I expect no difference as the MD5 is already computed un small chunks and bigger chunks are split in small one internally and computed sequentially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I was trying to say in the comments, it will depend on lots of things like the speed of your disk subsystem, your CPU performance and so on.

Here is an example. Create a 120GB file and check its size:

```
dd if=/dev/random of=junk bs=1g count=120

ls -lh junk
-rw-r--r--  1 mark  staff   120G  5 Oct 13:34 junk
```

Checksum in one go:

```
time md5sum junk
3c8fb0d5397be5a8b996239f1f5ce2f0  junk

real    3m55.713s       <--- 4 minutes
user    3m28.441s
sys     0m24.871s
```

Checksum in 10GB chunks, with 12 CPU cores in parallel:

```
time parallel -k --pipepart --recend '' --recstart '' --block 10G -a junk md5sum
29010b411a251ff467a325bfbb665b0d  -
793f02bb52407415b2bfb752827e3845  -
bf8f724d63f972251c2973c5bc73b68f  -
d227dcb00f981012527fdfe12b0a9e0e  -
5d16440053f78a56f6233b1a6849bb8a  -
dacb9fb1ef2b564e9f6373a4c2a90219  -
ba40d6e7d6a32e03fabb61bb0d21843a  -
5a5ee62d91266d9a02a37b59c3e2d581  -
95463c030b73c61d8d4f0e9c5be645de  -
4bcd7d43849b65d98d9619df27c37679  -
92bc1f80d35596191d915af907f4d951  -
44f3cb8a0196ce37c323e8c6215c7771  -

real    1m0.046s      <--- 1 minute
user    4m51.073s
sys     3m51.335s
```

It takes 1/4 of the time on my machine, but your mileage will vary... depending on your disk subsystem, your CPU etc.

Comment: Thanks for the testing! I don't have enough disk space to do it. I'll go and run against the whole file.